# Can the JS array length property ever return a negative value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Would there ever be an instance when the JavaScript array length property returns a negative value? I'm assuming the answer is no, but I was wondering if there would ever be a need to account for negative values when comparing the length of an array in an if statement, for example.

```
var x = y.length;

if (x === 0) {
    return false;
  } else if (x > 0) {
    return true;
  } else alert("error"); // is this necessary?
}
```

Comment: I would think it would definitely never be negative.  But could it be undefined?

Comment: @xdhmoore no, it can only be a natural number (0 or greater).

Comment: Can you think of an example of how the `.length` could possibly be negative?

Comment: How certain are you that `y` is an array? It could be some other kind of object, with or without a `.length` property.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No.

The [spec for the `length` property says](https://es5.github.io/#x15.4.5.2):

> The `length` property of this Array object is a data property whose value is always numerically greater than the name of every deletable property whose name is an array index.

There cannot be -1 properties.

Also, and more explicitly, the [spec for `Array` says](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/index.html#sec-15.4):

> Every `Array` object has a `length` property whose value is always a nonnegative integer less than 2<sup>32</sup>.

**Update:**
Answer still holds for [ES2020](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-properties-of-array-instances-length)

Comment: I had read on w3schools: "Return Value: A Number, representing the number of elements in the array object", which isn't as explicit as your source. This is what lead to my question.

Comment: @UncleSlug—[*w3schools*](http://www.w3fools.com/) is a very ordinary site, do not trust it.

Comment: BTW, the current standard is [*ECMA-262 ed 6*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html) aka ECMAScript 2015. ;-)

Comment: I am not quibbling with your fine answer, but I want to point out that the first quoted sentence from the spec is shockingly vague. (1) It does not state what the `length` value is supposed to be if the Array object is empty (that is, if it has no deletable property). What value is numerically greater than something that does not exist? (2) It does not state that (for non-empty Arrays) the `length` must be "numerically 1 more than the highest deletable property whose name is an array index". It just states that `length` must be higher than any index.

Comment: @cybersam—unfortunately, it's not all in one place. There is also "*Every Array object has a length property whose value is always a nonnegative integer less than 2^32.*" in [*ECMASCript 2015 §9.4.2*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array-exotic-objects). And yes, the length isn't necessarily *always* 1 greater, it's just *at least* one greater.

Comment: So, according to both quoted sentences, it is legal for an ECMAScript implementation to always return a `length` value of (2^32-1) for every Array?

Comment: @cybersam–yes, provided that's what it's been set to and noting that length is affected by operations on the array such as *push*, *splice*, *pop*, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Not normally (as other answers have pointed out), but **an object that is an instance of an array can have a negative property called length**

```
var b = Object.create([]);
b.length = -1;

alert(b instanceof Array)
alert(b.length);
```

Comment: Although, `Array.isArray(b) == false`

Comment: This highlights a weakness of *instanceof* that has been long known and why it's not used to test whether an object is an instance of something. ;-)

Comment: yes for both comments. serves as a reminder that the nicer looking check is not always the best :-)

Answer (score 3):

No, it can't.
Moreover, if you try doing this `arr.length = -1` it will throw you an exception

Answer (score 2):

No it cannot. [MDN says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length).

> The value of the length property is an integer with a positive sign and a value less than 2 to the 32nd power (232).

Answer (score 0):

As said here on Mozilla Developer site (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length), "the length property represents an unsigned, 32-bit integer that specifies the number of elements in an array.".
As you can see, it's an unsigned integer of 32 bits.
If it's unsigned, then it cannot be negative.

Comment: Check again, clear your cache. Latest update was, oh, 30 seconds before my comment. ;-)